# Modifying a Force Layout - using indexes rather than references gives TypeError

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a simple D3 force-directed layout, based on the [Modifying a Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) example, which works fine, using hard-coded data updated using `setTimeout` callbacks:

[image]

However, I will be loading the data dynamically from the server as JSON, so would like the link `source` and `target` to be specified as indexes into the `nodes` array, rather than references to the actual JavaScript node objects. This option is described in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout);

> Note: the values of the source and target attributes may be initially
>   specified as indexes into the nodes array; these will be replaced by
>   references after the call to start.

As a first step, I have tried modifying the example to use indexes; in the snippet below:

```
var a = {id: "a"}, b = {id: "b"}, c = {id: "c"};
nodes.push(a, b, c);
links.push({source: a, target: b},{source: a, target: c},{source: b, target: c});
start(); // joins the data, (re)starts the d3.layout.force
```

I change just a single line to use indexes into the nodes as follows:

```
links.push({source: 0, target: 1},{source: 0, target: 2},{source: 1, target: 2});
```

However, this results in a JavaScript error from `d3.v3.min.js` (Firefox 35.0.1):

```
TypeError: u is undefined
```

and the graph is only partially created - all 3 nodes are shown, but only one link:

[image]

Is is possible to use indexes in this manner?

Comment: What you want is certainly possible. See http://jsdatav.is/visuals.html?id=11550728. Not sure how you're triggering the layout. Are you only running one tick?

Comment: I'm binding a `tick` function to the `d3.layout.force` in the normal way, as shown at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795 so there are multiple ticks, and the graph is animated, even though it's created incorrectly.

Comment: I missed the fact that you were changing the data after starting the layout. Lars is right; you can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using indices in this way isn't possible with the current implementation of the force layout. When you start the layout, all indices in the links are replaced by references to the objects (this is why the documentation says that you can use indices, see lines 223-229 of [the source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js)). When you push indices without (re)starting the layout, this substitution doesn't happen and the code breaks.

You have two choices to make this work -- either push references to the node objects, or call `.start()` on the force layout after each push. Note that for the latter you should also stop the layout before pushing and all forces will be re-initialised, making the layout very "jumpy" every time you change something.

It sounds like in your case pushing references to node objects rather than indices wouldn't be a problem though, as you have access to the array of nodes. All you need to do then is index into it, as done in the D3 source.

Comment: The original code already calls `start()` after each `push()` - this is shown in the [original example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795), but I'll update the question to make this more obvious.

Comment: Yes, but it's not stopping the layout before changing the links -- the error occurs when the data has been modified but the layout not restarted yet.

Comment: OK, I have added `force.stop()` at the start of each `setTimeout` callback that modifies the links - but I get exactly the same problem.

Comment: The example that you're modifying calls `force.start()` (and therefore the substitution) only at the end of the `start()` function, but uses the data that this gets you in the key function -- you're not meant to use this example with indices :) It works for me if I move the call to `force.start()` to the beginning of the function: http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/0bb19eef2610469249b9